# ACER SP11-31-C2W3 not booting from usb properly

Tags: system-installation, acer, bios

I'm trying to put lubuntu on my new **ACER SP111-31-C2W3 with InsydeH20 Rev 5.0 Bios**. Made a live usb (using unetbootin & rufus for UFEI w/ GPT the & ISO from the lunbuntu site), works fine on my other PC.
When I try on the acer it picks up the USB as a boot option, but when it starts it's a black screen with the one white underline. Looks like when it boots and the report text is shown, but no text is there.
I'm planning on reformatting the whole drive and only use linux, if it makes a difference.

Comment: Do not use Unetbootin. If doing it from Windows, Canonical currently recommends Rufus (make sure the option for UEFI/GPT is selected before burning). You other PC has BIOS, reason why it booted.

Comment: Used Rufus with GPT partitioning for UFEI, same result